# How to prove a concentration isoperimetric inequality for a non-Lipschitz function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, jacobians, lipschitz-spaces

Definition $1$. A probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ satisfies c-isoperimetry if for any bounded L-Lipschitz $f: \mathbb{R}^{d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and any $t \geq 0$,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[|f(x)-\mathbb{E}[f]| \geq t] \leq 2 e^{-\frac{d t^{2}}{2 c L^{2}}}
\end{align}
In general, if a scalar random variable $X$ satisfies

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[|X| \geq t] \leq 2 e^{-t^{2} / 2C}
\end{align}

then we say $X$ is $C$-subgaussian.

---

Can I derive the following definition directly?

Definition $1^{*}$. A probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^{d_1} \times \mathbb{R}^{d_2}$ satisfies c-isoperimetry if for any **non-Lipschitz** $h_{\omega_b \omega_t}: \mathbb{R}^{d_1} \times \mathbb{R}^{d_2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{q}$, and any $t \geq 0$,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[|h_{\omega_b \omega_t}(s,p)-\mathbb{E}[h_{\omega_b \omega_t}]| \geq t] \leq 2 e^{-\frac{d_1 d_2 t^{2}}{2 c L^{2}}}
\end{align}
In general, if a scalar random variable $X$ satisfies

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[|X| \geq t] \leq 2 e^{-t^{2} / 2C}
\end{align}

then we say $X$ is $C$-subgaussian.

---

**Info about $h(s,p)$**

all was here are weights. All functions are neural net parameterized functions and hence following the Lipschitz property.
$L_B$ and $L_T$ are Lipschitz  constant.

$$
\mathcal{B}:=\left\{\mathrm{B}_{\boldsymbol{w}} \mid \mathrm{B}: \mathbb{R}^{d_{1}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{q}, \operatorname{Lip}\left(\mathrm{B}_{\boldsymbol{w}}\right) \leq L_{B} \&\|\boldsymbol{w}\| \leq W_{B}\right\}
$$
$$
\mathcal{T}:=\left\{\mathbf{T}_{\boldsymbol{w}} \mid \mathbf{T}: \mathbb{R}^{d_{2}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{q}, \operatorname{Lip}\left(\mathbf{T}_{\boldsymbol{w}}\right) \leq L_{T} \&\|\boldsymbol{w}\| \leq W_{T}\right\}
$$
Now consider the following function class of all possible inner-products between the two,
$$
\mathcal{H}:=\left\{h_{\boldsymbol{w}_{b}, \boldsymbol{w}_{t}} \mid \mathbb{R}^{d_{1}} \times \mathbb{R}^{d_{2}} \ni(s, p) \mapsto h(s, p):=\left\langle\mathrm{B}_{\boldsymbol{w}_{b}}(s), \mathbf{T}_{\boldsymbol{w}_{t}}(p)\right\rangle \in \mathbb{R}, \mathrm{B}_{\boldsymbol{w}_{b}} \in \mathcal{B} \& \mathbf{T}_{\boldsymbol{w}_{t}} \in \mathcal{T}\right\}
$$

---

Is $h(s,p)$ a Lipschitz?

NO! There is no way (as per my knowledge) to show it as a Lipschitz function as,

$f(x) = x$ is a Lipschitz function with Lipschitz constant $1$, $f*f = x^2$ which is not Lipschitz

However I have proven this inequality,

\begin{align}
&B_\omega(s)-B_\omega\left(s^{\prime}\right) \leq L_B\left\|s-s^{\prime}\right\|\\
&B_\omega(s) \cdot T_\omega(p)-B_\omega\left(s^{\prime}\right) \cdot T_\omega(p) \leq L_B\left\|s-s^{\prime}\right\| T_\omega(p)\\
&\left\langle B_\omega(s)-B_\omega\left(s^{\prime}\right), T_\omega(p)\right\rangle \leq L_B M_T\left\|s-s^{\prime}\right\| \quad \text { where } M_T=\sup _{\omega_t, p} T_{\omega_t}(p) \text {1.}\\
&T_\omega(p)-T_\omega\left(p^{\prime}\right) \leqslant L_T\left\|p-p^{\prime}\right\|\\
&T_\omega(p) \cdot B_\omega\left(s^{\prime}\right)-T_\omega\left(p^{\prime}\right) \cdot B_\omega\left(s^{\prime}\right) \leq L_T\left\|p-p^{\prime}\right\| \cdot B_\omega\left(s^{\prime}\right)\\
&\left\langle B_\omega\left(s^{\prime}\right), T_\omega(p)-T_\omega\left(p^{\prime}\right)\right\rangle \leqslant L_T M_B\left\|p-p^{\prime}\right\| \quad \text { Where, } M_B=\sup_{\omega_b s^{\prime}} B_{\omega_b}\left(s^{\prime}\right) \text {2.}\\
\end{align}

Adding (1) + (2),

$\left\langle B_{\omega_b}(s), T_{\omega_t}(p)\right\rangle-\left\langle B_{\omega_b}\left(s^{\prime}\right), T_{\omega_t}\left(p^{\prime}\right)\right\rangle$
$\leq L_B M_T\left\|s-s^{\prime}\right\|$
$+L_T M_B\left\|p-p^i\right\|$

So for $h_{\omega_b \omega_t}$ the **?(I guess this is not Lipschitz)** constant will be at most
$$
\therefore\left(L_B M_T+L_T M_B\right)
$$

I am struggling to come up with a solution for $h_{\omega_b \omega_t}$. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

---

Thanks to @dohmatob. I find the mentioned paper fascinating. But there I am facing some issues. If one can give any direction,will be a great help.

I was reading this [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00440-014-0579-3). In that paper, I find **Theorem 3** fascinating!

Theorem $3.3$ Assume that $X$ is a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that for some constants $L>0, \gamma \geq 1 / 2$, all smooth bounded functions $f$ and all $p \geq 2$,
$$
\|f(X)-\mathbb{E} f(X)\|_p \leq L p^\gamma\||\nabla f(X)|\|_p
$$
For any smooth function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of class $\mathcal{C}^D$ and $p \geq 2$ if $\mathbf{D}^D f(X) \in L^p$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|f(X)-\mathbb{E} f(X)\|_p \leq & C_D\left(\sum_{\mathcal{J} \in P_D} L^D p^{(\gamma-1 / 2) D+\# \mathcal{J} / 2}\|\| \mathbf{D}^D f(X)\left\|_{\mathcal{J}}\right\|_p\right.\\
&\left.+\sum_{1 \leq d \leq D-1} \sum_{\mathcal{J} \in P_d} L^d p^{(\gamma-1 / 2) d+\# \mathcal{J} / 2}\left\|\mathbb{E} \mathbf{D}^d f(X)\right\|_{\mathcal{J}}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Moreover, if $\mathbf{D}^D f$ is bounded uniformly on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then for all $t>0$,
$$
\mathbb{P}(|f(X)-\mathbb{E} f(X)| \geq t) \leq 2 \exp \left(-\frac{1}{C_D} \eta_f(t)\right)
$$
where
$$
\begin{aligned}
\eta_f(t) &=\min (A, B), \\
A &=\min _{\mathcal{J} \in P_D}\left(\left(\frac{t}{L^D \sup _{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}\left\|\mathbf{D}^D f(x)\right\|_{\mathcal{J}}}\right)^{2 /((2 \gamma-1) D+\# \mathcal{J})}\right) \\
B &=\min _{1 \leq d \leq D-1} \min _{\mathcal{J} \in P_d}\left(\left(\frac{t}{L^d\left\|\mathbb{E} \mathbf{D}^d f(X)\right\|_{\mathcal{J}}}\right)^{2 /((2 \gamma-1) d+\# \mathcal{J})}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

I am particularly interested to calculate that $\eta$  for my function. Also, I have not understood the partition norm quite well.

**The definition of the norm**

[image]

Their $D^{d} f(X)$ definition is like this :

[image]

---

I am interested to find $\eta$ for a multivariable function $h (s,p) := \left\langle\sigma(B_1(s)), \sigma(T_1(p))\right\rangle$. I am assuming  $ \sigma = \text{Sigmoid} ,\gamma=1$ and $L=C \sqrt{D_{\text {Poin }}}, D = 2$.

**Now in this setting, I need to find Jacobian of that h(s,p) and then I have to take the partition norm of it. How to do that?**

Sigmoid function $\varsigma_\alpha(x)$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\varsigma_\alpha(x) &=\frac{1}{1+e^{-\alpha x}}=\frac{\tanh (\alpha x / 2)+1}{2} \\
\varsigma_\alpha^{\prime}(x) &=\alpha \varsigma_\alpha(x)\left\{1-\varsigma_\alpha(x)\right\} \\
\varsigma_\alpha^{\prime \prime}(x) &=\alpha^2 \varsigma_\alpha(x)\left\{1-\varsigma_\alpha(x)\right\}\left\{1-2 \varsigma_\alpha(x)\right\}
\end{aligned}
$$

TIA

Comment: Does this help ? "Concentration of Non-Lipschitz Functions ..." https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00440-014-0579-3.pdf

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/q/432570/37212, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4552628/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).